# How create a simulation (pendulum, projectile motion) in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, physics, simulator

I created a program that generates the placement of the pendulum, length, position of the ball, velocity, angles, and trajectory. The program's task is to find a solution where the ball can land safely through a 'cave'. The pendulum is inside an 85.75 by 66.75 area, length < 65, ball radius = 1.25

I want to create a simulation of the experiment in pygame, that will run my 1st program to generate all the parameters, and then display the solution and path the ball will follow. I have spent the past couple days learning pygame, but can't figure out how to 'transfer' my first program. Ive looked at other pendulum simulators, and tried to change it to work for my experiment, but I got lost and decided to come to StackOverflow for advice. If anyone could show me where I went wrong in making the simulation, it would be very appreciated.

first program

```
import math as m
import numpy as np

# Variables
c = 28.5
Wx = 20
Wy = 30
d = 85.75
f = 66.75
g = 385.826772
ay = -g

# Calculations
for theta in np.arange(1, 90, .01):
    l = Wx + (m.tan(m.radians(theta)) * (f - Wy))
    if Wx <= l <= d:
        phi = 90 - theta
        v = (d - l) / m.sin(m.radians(phi))
        vc = v - 1.25
        if (f - Wy) <= v <= 65:
            h = f - (m.cos(m.radians(phi)) * v)
            a = v * m.sin(m.radians(theta))
            b = v * m.cos(m.radians(theta))
            by = f - b
            bx = l - a
            if h <= f and by <= c:
                vel = m.sqrt((2 * g) * (h - by)) * .95
                velx = vel * m.cos(m.radians(theta))
                vely = vel * m.sin(m.radians(theta))
                y = (-vely**2) / (2 * ay)
                Ymax = y + by
                if m.isclose(Ymax, c, abs_tol= .01):
                    t1 = -vely / ay
                    t2 = m.sqrt((2 * Ymax) / -ay)
                    T = t1 + t2
                    x = velx * T
                    print(' l: {0} v: {1}  vc: {2} h: {3}\n bx: {4} by: {5}\n vel: {6} velx: {7} vely: {8}\n y: {9} Ymax: {10} x: {11} T: {12}\n theta: {13} phi: {14}\n'
                          .format(l, v, vc, h, bx, by, vel, velx, vely, y, Ymax, x, T, theta, phi))
```

Simulator

```
import pygame
import numpy as np
import math as m
from math import pi

# Tarzan Variables
c = 28.5
Wy = 30
Wx = 20
d = 85.75
f = 66.75

# Colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)

# Pygame Variables
theta = 0
v = 0
vel = 0
acc = 0

# Start Pygame
width, height = 900, 700
pygame.init()
background = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


# Tarzan
class Pendulum(object):
    def __init__(self, XY, l, radius):
        self.x = XY[0]
        self.y = XY[1]
        self.l = l
        self.radius = radius

    def draw(self, bg):
        pygame.draw.line(bg, white, (self.l, 0), (self.x, self.y), 4)
        pygame.draw.circle(bg, red, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
        pygame.draw.line(bg, green, (Wx, height), (Wx, (height - Wy)), 4)
        # pygame.draw.circle(bg, white, (self.l, 0), int(v)) --- to see if pendulum is following an arc


def theta_v():
    v = m.sqrt(m.pow(pendulum.x - (width / 2), 2) + m.pow(pendulum.y, 2))
    theta = m.asin(((pendulum.x - (width / 2)) / v))
    return theta, v


def get_path(theta, v):
    pendulum.x = round(pendulum.l + (v * m.sin(theta)))
    pendulum.y = round(v * m.cos(theta))
    pendulum.l = pendulum.x - (v * m.sin(m.radians(theta)))


def redraw():
    background.fill(black)
    pendulum.draw(background)
    pygame.display.update()


pendulum = Pendulum((75, 67), 500, 15)
# Close Pygame
stop = False
acceleration = False
while not stop:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            stop = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pendulum = Pendulum(pygame.mouse.get_pos(), 500, 15)
            theta, v = theta_v()
            acceleration = True

    if acceleration:
        acc = -.005 * m.sin(theta)
        vel += acc
        vel *= .995
        theta += vel
        get_path(theta, v)
        print(pendulum.x, pendulum.y, (theta * (180 / pi)), v, vel, pendulum.l)
    redraw()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Please define what you mean by "transfer"?  Transfer it to what form?  Do you mean merge the "first program" code into the "Simulator" code?

Comment: Kinglsey, you are correct, when I say 'transfer' i mean implementing the 'first program' into the simulator code. I want to use the results to create a simulation fo the experiment.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wanted this program to create a hanging pendulum swinging around correctly. There were a few things wrong with your code:

1. In order to calculate your pendulum.l value, you converted theta to radians first. As your theta value was already in radians, This was absolutely not nessary, and makes your pendulum.l value almost not change.
2. When you now execute your code, you might see that the attachment point of the pendulum is changing. This is because you are changing pendulum.l, and use it for drawingg the pendulum at the same time. This can be easily fixed by saving your first pendulum.l value, and use that value to draw the pendulum.
3. Your program keeps attampting to move the pendulum forever, giving sometimes unexpected results. You should add some way to figure out whether the pendulum is still moving (probably by chenking whether one of the variables is not changing enough - I had not enough time to figure it out)
4. Rounding your x and y values causes a buildup if rounding errors on the end, making the pendulium coming to a stop while still being tilted a bit. You can just round while drawing the penduluim to fix this.

The entire code should look like this:

```
import time
import pygame
import numpy as np
import math as m
from math import pi

# Tarzan Variables
c = 28.5
Wy = 30
Wx = 20
d = 85.75
f = 66.75

# Colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
green = (0, 255, 0)

# Pygame Variables
theta = 0
v = 0
vel = 0
acc = 0

# Start Pygame
width, height = 900, 700
pygame.init()
background = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


# Tarzan
class Pendulum(object):
    def __init__(self, XY, l, radius):
        self.x = XY[0]
        self.y = XY[1]
        self.l = l
        self.lfixed = l
        self.radius = radius

    def draw(self, bg):
        pygame.draw.line(bg, white, (self.lfixed, 0), (self.x, self.y), 4)
        pygame.draw.circle(bg, red, (round(self.x), round(self.y)), self.radius)
        pygame.draw.line(bg, green, (Wx, height), (Wx, (height - Wy)), 4)
        # pygame.draw.circle(bg, white, (self.l, 0), int(v)) --- to see if pendulum is following an arc


def theta_v():
    v = m.sqrt(m.pow(pendulum.x - (width / 2), 2) + m.pow(pendulum.y, 2))
    theta = m.asin(((pendulum.x - (width / 2)) / v))
    return theta, v


def get_path(theta, v):
    pendulum.x = pendulum.l + (v * m.sin(theta))
    pendulum.y = v * m.cos(theta)
    pendulum.l = pendulum.x - (v * m.sin((theta)))


def redraw():
    background.fill(black)
    pendulum.draw(background)
    pygame.display.update()


pendulum = Pendulum((75, 67), 500, 15)
# Close Pygame
stop = False
acceleration = False
while not stop:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            stop = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pendulum = Pendulum(pygame.mouse.get_pos(), 500, 15)
            theta, v = theta_v()
            acceleration = True

    if acceleration:
        acc = -.005 * m.sin(theta)
        vel += acc
        vel *= .995
        theta += vel
        get_path(theta, v)
        print(pendulum.x, pendulum.y, (theta * (180 / pi)), v, vel, pendulum.l)
    redraw()
    time.sleep(0.1)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```